# Is there a callback after map.fitBounds?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My code :

```
if(!bounds.isEmpty()) {
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    if (map.getZoom() > 11) {
        map.setZoom(11);
    }   
}
```

but I see that `map.setZoom(11);` could be called before `.fitBounds` end. So the result is not what I aspect for.

Is there a way to manage a callback when `.fitBound` finish?

Comment: Why are you using setZoom?  `fitBounds` will automatically adjust the viewport, including the zoom level to fit the bounds object passed to the method.  There is no callback available.  You could use the `bounds_changed` event and include an event listener for that, but anytime the user pans or zooms, the event would fire.  Your best bet is to use fitBounds.

Comment: Yes! But if only bound is found, the zoom is at high level. I want lower than this...

Comment: I don't know how your app is designed, but when would you not be able to determine the bounds?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try this:

```
 if(!bounds.isEmpty()) {
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
        if (map.getZoom() > 11) {
            map.setZoom(11);
        }  
    });
}
```

Comment: @markzzz, in case you are still scratching your head about this, the "idle" event will trigger after the fitBounds method finishes adjusting the map.  So, fitBounds doesn't have a callback, but idle does, and idle always triggers after any map movement ends.

Comment: Thank you! I had exactly the same problem and wondered if such callback was possible after map.fitBounds(). Here your `addListenerOnce()` and 'idle" were exactly the solution I needed. Additional note, we could also use regular `addListener()` and then remove it with `removeListener()` after the callback operation completes.